# Performance issue in ExtJS 3.2 grid

Tags: extjs3

I'm using `ExtJS 3.2.0`. In UI its allow users to scan their items to the `grid`. Items keep in the `jsp`. Once user scanned an item it will add new row to the `grid`. When count increase it'll take much time to add to the `grid`. Is there any solution to overcome this in 3.2.0 version ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is called buffered rendering. Buffered rendering is the process of only rendering the rows visible to the user, so that a grid can have a large number of records without a major impact on performance. Unfortunately, this is not available in [Ext JS 3.2.0](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.0/docs/). It was introduced in [Ext JS 4.2.0](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer).